# Samples of malware that trigger AV but are harmless

Tags: malware

Is there any malware currently downloadable by an amateur that will be detected as malware by anti-virus programs, but does not do much (is harmless or had its C&C servers shut down)? I'm preparing a brief presentation on malware and AVs to my boss. If that does not work or there are none, is there any ransomware that encrypts the file with a known key so it can also be easily decrypted?

Answer (score 12):

The [EICAR anti-malware testfile](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-intended-use.html) is a small and innocent program which is detected by (almost?) every AV. All the program does is print a short string, i.e. no harm is done. It is specifically intended to be used to test AV, i.e. even a AV without current signatures should be able to detect this "malware".

Answer (score -3):

Not all AV engines are equal. Malware itself is code that has malicious intent, so it's a bit ironic. However, I understand your request for malicious code that may lean on the recon and aggregation side of things.

Here's a link to some malware that's relatively harmless as it's used for code/behavioral analysis for teaching purposes.

What I would do is run the malware through VirusTotal or some other automated malware sandbox solution and note down which AV engines trip and which don't. Install an AV solution for each those scenarios and compare.

https://app.box.com/s/1ox2fy61b4mdkis7ymcy6iecef0tckh3